# How to find all managed attached objects in EntityManager (JPA)

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

Is there a way to get all objects which are currently attached in the entity manager?
I want to write some monitoring code which will report the number of attached objects and their classes.
Meaning finding all objects which were loaded by previous queries and find operations into the entity manager.
I'm using EclipseLink, so a specific solution is good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EclipseLink's JPA interface pretty much wraps its native code such that an EntityManager uses a UnitOfWork session underneath (and the EMF wraps a ServerSession).  You need to get at the UnitOfWork if you want to see what entities it is managing.

If using JPA 2.0, you can use the EntityManager unwrap method:

```
UnitOfWork uow = em.unwrap(UnitOfWork.class);
```

otherwise, use some casting

```
UnitOfWork uow = ((EntityManagerImpl)em).getUnitOfWork();
```

From there, the UnitOfWork has a list of all registered (aka managed) entities.  You can use the UOW to directly log what it has using the `printRegisteredObjects()` method, or obtain it yourself using `getCloneMapping().keySet()`.

You can also see deleted objects by using `hasDeletedObjects()` and then `getDeletedObjects().keySet()` if there are any, as and the same for new objects using `hasNewObjectsInParentOriginalToClone()` and `getNewObjectsCloneToOriginal().keySet()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use JPA in a lot of ways i am still unaware of, and there is a lot going on under the hood in eclipselink that i still do not fully understand, but it looks like it is possible to see into the persistence context. USE THIS CODE AT YOUR OWN RISK. it is only meant to give you a hint that it is possible to inspect the context. (whether the code is right or wrong i'm posting it because it would have helped me when i was trying to decide whether to use eclipselink. there doesn't seem to be much in the way of documentation about how to do this properly.)

```
public void saveChanges() {
    Date now = new Date();

    JpaEntityManager jem = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class);
    UnitOfWorkImpl uow = jem.unwrap(UnitOfWorkImpl.class);

    // inserts

    for (Object entity : uow.getNewObjectsCloneToOriginal().keySet()) {
        if (entity instanceof IAuditedEntity) {
            IAuditedEntity auditedEntity = (IAuditedEntity) entity;
            auditedEntity.setAuditedUserId(this.userId);
            auditedEntity.setAuditedAt(now);
            auditedEntity.setCreatedAt(now);
        }
    }

    // updates

    UnitOfWorkChangeSet uowChangeSet = (UnitOfWorkChangeSet) uow.getUnitOfWorkChangeSet();
    if (uowChangeSet != null) {
        List<IAuditedEntity> toUpdate = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Entry<Object, ObjectChangeSet> entry : uowChangeSet.getCloneToObjectChangeSet().entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().hasChanges()) {
                if (entry.getKey() instanceof IAuditedEntity) {
                    toUpdate.add((IAuditedEntity) entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
        for (IAuditedEntity auditedEntity : toUpdate) {
            auditedEntity.setAuditedUserId(this.userId);
            auditedEntity.setAuditedAt(now);
        }
    }

    // deletions

    Project jpaProject = uow.getProject();
    boolean anyAuditedDeletions = false;

    for (Object entity : uow.getDeletedObjects().keySet()) {
        if (entity instanceof IAuditedEntity) {
            anyAuditedDeletions = true;
            DeletedEntity deletion = new DeletedEntity();
            deletion.setTableName(jpaProject.getClassDescriptor(entity.getClass()).getTableName());
            deletion.setEntityId(((IAuditedEntity) entity).getId());
            deletion.setAuditedUserId(this.userId);
            em.persist(deletion);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by inspecting the entities on `MetaModel` which can be obtained from any `EntityManager`.

**Example usage:**

```
EntityManager em = // get your EM however...
for(EntityType<?> entityType : em.getMetaModel().getEntities()) 
{
    Class<?> managedClass = entityType.getBindableJavaType();
    System.out.println("Managing type: " + managedClass.getCanonicalName());
}
```

This example will print out all of the class types being managed by the EntityManager.  To get all of the actual objects being managed, simply query all objects of that type on the EntityManager.

---

**Update:**

As of JPA 2.0 you can cache results that will be managed by `javax.persistence.Cache`.  However, with plain JPA there is no way to actually retrieve the objects stored in the cache, the best you can do is check if a certain object is in the Cache via [`Cache.contains(Class cls, Object pk)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cache.html#contains(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object)):

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().contains(MyData.class, somePK);
```

However, EclipseLink extends `Cache` with `JpaCache`.  You can use this to actually get the object from the cache via [`JpaCache.getObject(Class cls, Object id)`](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.1/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/JpaCache.html#getObject(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object)).  This doesn't return a collection or anything, but it's the next best thing.

Unfortunately, if you want to actually access objects in the cache, you will need to manage this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I was asking for something else. I want to find all attached objects already loaded into the entity manager from previous fine /  queries operations.

Comment: what do you mean by *loaded into the entity manager*?  Is that not all objects that are of the type that the EM manages?

Comment: No. If I did a query which returned 100 objects from class A and another query which loaded 100 objects of class B, they are all managed by the entity manager. I want to iterate these 200 objects in memory.

Comment: now I understand your question, updated my answer accordingly.  unfortunately there is no nice way to do this, but why not just re-run your queries?  Since the objects are cached it would be just as fast as running some `cache.getAllObjects()` method.

Comment: we are lots of developers, and once a large number of objects are loaded the entity manager operations becomes significantly slower. I need to write code to monitor large transactions and find potential problems.

Comment: you shouldn't have to manually cache objects that are already internally cached by JPA, since JPA does caching for you under the covers.  I recommend that you tune your caching settings instead of writing special code to do manual caching.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see such an option in the `EntityManager` interface. There is only a [`contains(Object entity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method but you need to pass the conrete objects and they are the checked for existentnce in the PersistenceContext. Also looking at the [`PersistenceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) interface i dont see such an option.